# foreach (parallel) for matrix operation in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am trying to convert the following for loop to foreach to take the advantage of parallel.

```
dt = data.frame(t(data.frame(a=sample(1:10,10), b=sample(1:10,10), c=sample(1:10,10), d=sample(1:10,10))))

X = as.matrix(dt)
c = ncol(X)
itemnames=names(dt)

sm=matrix(0,c,c)
colnames(sm)=itemnames
row.names(sm)=itemnames
for (j in 1:c){
  ind=setdiff(1:c,j)
  print(ind)
  print(j)
  sm[j,ind]=sign(X[j]-X[ind])
  print(sm[j,ind])
}

cvec = 1:c

r = foreach(d = cvec, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
  ind = setdiff(1:10,d)
  sm[d,ind]=sign(X[d]-X[ind])
  }
```

With for loop I am getting the 10*10 matrix where the above sign function repelaces the off diagonal elements and it would be 0 for diagonal elements.
But with foreach, I am getting 10*9 matrix, its missing the diagonal elements and everything else is same. 
Please help me to get the same output as for loop. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here, since you are only using the first ten elements of you matrix. This can be done without any loops:

```
sign(outer(X[1:10], X[1:10], FUN = "-"))
```

In addition, I am not sure that parallel processing will be faster for this kind of problem, even assuming that the real case is much bigger. But if you want to use `foreach`, you should not assign to the global `sm` within the loop and instead return a suitable vector in the end:

```
foreach(d = cvec, .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
  ind <- setdiff(cvec,d)
  res <- rep(0, 10)
  res[ind] <- sign(X[d]-X[ind])
  res
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ralf, it worked. The real case is much bigger, I am trying out on a small data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign to a matrix in parallel, you'll need a shared matrix:

```
# devtools::install_github("privefl/bigstatsr")
library(bigstatsr)
sm <- FBM(c, c)

library(foreach)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(3)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
r = foreach(d = cvec, .combine = c) %dopar% {
  ind = setdiff(1:10,d)
  sm[d,ind]=sign(X[d]-X[ind])
  NULL
}
parallel::stopCluster(cl)

sm[]
```